# Python 3.10 is the default PyCharm update for pyspark/spark 3.0.0.preview - are these two compatible?

Tags: python, java, scala, hadoop, pyspark

There is documentation that indicates Python 3.9 is the last version compatible with [Spark 3.0.0.preview](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-3-0-0.html).   For someone new at setting up compatibility on Windows using Hadoop, Spark, Scala, Python, and PyCharm, the number of possibilities for compatibility is daunting and while browsing through the first few, given the course suggestions, it is trying to find python and spark compatibility.  The version of interpreter used for the Anaconda3 is 3.8.8.

In the image below, it would appear from the school of hard knocks, the compatibility may not exist.  The [downloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kzAH.png) are not indicative of versioning for Python.   The Scala with the course is 2.11.  The latest release also indicates 2.12 is needed for Scala (same link).  Somewhere within all these choices (Using Windows 10), there is a solution but it is elusive.  Hadoop version seems to be an issue as well.  (Hadoop 2.7)

Other compatibility issues occur prior to setting Edit Configurations for each project and include missing files or access errors (this is a company machine - privileged management - but not full admin rights)

From the thread dump, there appears to be a log of information but being new again, it is difficult to sort through all the debug information.  Possibly the JDK is wrong? but it is the one suggested to use with JRE1.8.0_201.   I saw some issues as well about the possible space in "Program Files" being problematic with the JAVA_HOME path.  Java did not seem happy when during one of the trial setups, it was installed to a different directory.

```
    Anaconda3>pycharm
    CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
    2022-11-04 08:40:31,040 [   1132]   WARN - #c.i.o.f.i.FileTypeManagerImpl -
    com.adacore.adaintellij.file.AdaSpecFileType@4f671e00 from 'PluginDescriptor(name=Ada, id=com.adacore.Ada-IntelliJ, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.2\plugins\Ada-IntelliJ, version=0.6-dev, package=null, isBundled=false)' (class com.adacore.adaintellij.file.AdaSpecFileType) and
    com.adacore.adaintellij.file.AdaBodyFileType@22a64016 from 'PluginDescriptor(name=Ada, id=com.adacore.Ada-IntelliJ, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.2\plugins\Ada-IntelliJ, version=0.6-dev, package=null, isBundled=false)' (class com.adacore.adaintellij.file.AdaBodyFileType)
     both have the same .getDisplayName(): 'Ada'. Please override either one's getDisplayName() to something unique.
    com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException:
    com.adacore.adaintellij.file.AdaSpecFileType@4f671e00 from 'PluginDescriptor(name=Ada, id=com.adacore.Ada-IntelliJ, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.2\plugins\Ada-IntelliJ, version=0.6-dev, package=null, isBundled=false)' (class com.adacore.adaintellij.file.AdaSpecFileType) and
    com.adacore.adaintellij.file.AdaBodyFileType@22a64016 from 'PluginDescriptor(name=Ada, id=com.adacore.Ada-IntelliJ, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.2\plugins\Ada-IntelliJ, version=0.6-dev, package=null, isBundled=false)' (class com.adacore.adaintellij.file.AdaBodyFileType)
     both have the same .getDisplayName(): 'Ada'. Please override either one's getDisplayName() to something unique. 
2022-11-04 08:40:45,822 [  15914] SEVERE - #c.i.u.m.i.MessageBusImpl - PyCharm 2022.2.3  Build #PC-222.4345.23
2022-11-04 08:40:45,825 [  15917] SEVERE - #c.i.u.m.i.MessageBusImpl - JDK: 17.0.4.1; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2022-11-04 08:40:45,826 [  15918] SEVERE - #c.i.u.m.i.MessageBusImpl - OS: Windows 10
```

[image]

```
  [1]: https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6BGc.png
```

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use preview releases. It's been over 2 years since Spark 3 was released; use at least the latest minor release.

That being said, Spark 3 mostly is meant to be used with Hadoop 3. All should work fine on Windows, using Java 11 (your logs say 17)

You can use Scala 2.12 or 2.13 for Spark.

Pyspark support should be fine on Python 3.9. Don't use Anaconda if you don't need it. Download Python directly. `pip install pyspark`. That's it. You don't even need Hadoop to run Spark code.

And unclear why you're trying to run Pycharm from the terminal. Start with `spark-shell`, then if that works, then you can run `pyspark`. Then you can use `spark-submit`. Only once those work, should you realistically move towards an IDE.

Alternatively, don't pollute your host machine with a bunch of software, install Docker instead, and use that to run Jupyter with Spark pre-configured - https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/running.html